# How can I turn this code into a function? (Array to TextFields)

Tags: javascript, arrays, actionscript-3

Updated code that gets me closer. Something is wrong with the increment but I can't put my finger on it.

```
var myMovies:Array = ["Source Code", "Alice in Wonderland", "Zootopia", "Shrek", "Harry Potter"];

var inc:Number = 500; // starting vertical position
var increment:Number = 0;

function addField() {
      var textBox:TextField = new TextField(); // assigns a variable to create a new text field
      addChild(textBox); // adds the text field to the document
      textBox.x = 150; // formats horizontal positioning
      textBox.y = inc; // formats vertical positioning
      inc-= 100; // subtracts 100px from vertical positioning
      textBox.text = myMovies[increment];
     increment++;// inserts array string into text box // goes to and stops on frame 2
}


if (increment < 5) {
    addField(); 
} else { 
    gotoAndPlay(3); 
    }
```

Comment: What are you using to layout your text fields? Sounds like a positioning issue?

Comment: You were right - I've amended the code above to include positional formatting. :) Any tips are appreciated. Something is wrong with the counter that is preventing the code from working as proposed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reverse the initial array with **Array.reverse()** method: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#reverse()

```
myMovies = myMovies.reverse();
myText.text = myMovies.join("\n");
```

Well, lets make your script right.

```
var myMovies:Array = ["Source Code", "Alice in Wonderland", "Zootopia", "Shrek", "Harry Potter"];

// If you need the items to be sorted in backward order,
// uncomment the following line:

// myMovies = myMovies.reverse();

for (var i:int = 0; i < myMovies.length; i++)
{
    var aField:TextField = new TextField;

    aField.multiline = false;
    aField.wordWrap = false;
    aField.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
    aField.x = 100;
    aField.y = 100 + i * 100;
    aField.text = myMovies[i];
}
```

Comment: This only reverses the order though. I need it to appear either in one text box, or multiple textboxes, so the end result looks something like this:

My Favourite Movies

#1

#2

#3

#4

#5

but appears from #5 upwards.

Comment: I don't understand why it is a problem, but well, updated.

Comment: I'm still new so maybe I don't understand what you mean haha :') I'll try it. Sorry if I came across ignorant I didn't mean to!

Comment: @Lexii Don't apologize for ignorance, for it is easily remedied by asking questions :)  And hey, now you know, so you're doubly a winner :D

Comment: I still don't think this is what I need. Putting that piece of code in, the program does not display them one by one, from least to most favourite (where index[4] is most favourite).

Comment: Of course it is not. It is a **guideline** how to put them into one TextField in the designated order.

Comment: Hi all - I've amended the code to be closer to what I need. But still am struggling with the counter as it's not recognizing other array elements now. I'm sorry if these are silly questions, am still fairly new at all this. :) Thanks for your input though it's good to get opinions from people who have been in the game for awhile.

Comment: You confused **if** with **while**. I added another script to my answer that should probably work for you.